# How to increase the width of the page used by my text

Tags: formatting

I want to decrease the white space on either side of my body of text. Is there a specific property I can edit to do this, or would I need to import a package and use that?

I don't think it's particularly appropriate to include my code, so I won't unless I am told that it is actually relevent to the question.

I am using the `article` document class.

Comment: You can do that by hand, but i would certainly prefer to use package `geometry`.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to alter the margins: is that correct? If so, we will need to know what document class you are using (assuming LaTeX, of course).

Comment: I'm using the article class, and yes I do just want to adjust my margins

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like the others I prefer and would highly recommend the `geometry` package, (note that I have also included the `showframe` package which shows the margins). MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    %\usepackage{showframe} %This line can be used to clearly show the new margins

    \newgeometry{vmargin={15mm}, hmargin={12mm,17mm}}   % set the margins

    \begin{document}
    Insert your relatively wide text here
    \end{document}
```

An alternative package is `a4wide` which makes the page size more MS word like:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{a4wide}
    %\usepackage{showframe} %This line can be used to clearly show the new margins

    \begin{document}
    Insert your word like text here
    \end{document}
```

If for some reason you'd rather not use a package I highly recommend you visit the [WikiBooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_dimensions) site. Using the `\setlength` command:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    %\usepackage{showframe} % This line can be used to clearly show the new margins

    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{11pt}% the default is 31pt so decrease by 20pt
    \setlength{\textwidth}{430pt}% the default is 390pt so increase by 40pt

    \begin{document}
    Insert your 40 pt wider text here, note 1pt ≈ 0.3515mm
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `geometry` package:

```
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
```

Some classes (KOMA-Script, memoir) have internal means to do the same thing but the `geometry` package should work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something simple in the `geometry` package, such as adding `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` to the preamble for 1 inch margins.

Comment: While this might be a solution to the question, a full working example is much appreciated.